# How to refactor program that uses state monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, io, state, monads

I finished (well, almost) my first more-or-less useful project in Haskell. It consists of several modules and almost all the modules use `StateT` a lot.

Big picture is: on top level I need to work with state and IO simultaneously, so I use `StateT myState IO` monad transformer. It is OK and my code magically 'just works', but now I think that perhaps the code isn't perfect because a lot of functions in other modules are inside the monad transformer, so they potentially can perform IO, although they are pretty pure by their nature. And that's a bad thing.

Can you advise me how to refactor the program so that I can somehow write functions in the modules inside `State` monad, without any `IO`, but being able to combine this code with IO on top level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your function only needs StateT, you could give it a signature such as

```
incrementCounter :: (Monad m) => (StateT Counter m ())
incrementCounter = do count <- get
                      put (increment count)
                      return ()
```

That way your function needs to work with any Monad m (and can't rely on it being IO). At the top level you can instantiate m = IO.

Comment: In fact, if you use the `transformers` library, this is exactly the type that the compiler will infer